# Component definition is missing display name when using withAuthenticationRequired

Tags: reactjs, auth0

I have the following compile error

> Component definition is missing display name  react/display-name

My code:

```
import React from "react";
import {withAuthenticationRequired} from "@auth0/auth0-react";

function MyComponent () {
    return (<div>Hello</div>);
}

export default withAuthenticationRequired(MyComponent, {
    // Show a message while the user waits to be redirected to the login page.
    onRedirecting: () => <div>Redirecting you to the login page...</div>,
});
```

I tried solutions from similar questions, but it did not work. Disabling eslint **react/display-name** option is not what I expect.

Answer (score 0):

Answered in the issue on Github: https://github.com/auth0/auth0-react/issues/282#issuecomment-928051777

```js
export default withAuthenticationRequired(MyComponent, {
    onRedirecting: function OnRedirectingComponent() {
      return <div>Redirecting you to the login page...</div>
    },
});
```